# Look for an easy was to find a user selected date

Tags: java, android

I have a DatePickerDialog that opens up and you select the date. I want to find out what day that is. Monday Tuesday. You get the idea. I can get the date I just don't know how to find the day. Is there an easy was to do this? I have looked at the documentation on this and I don't see anything that is a getDay(int year, int date, int month) method. Is there one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create localized strings from dates use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) it will generate Strings from a Date object:

```
SimpleDayFormat dayFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E");
Log.d("Today", "Today is " + dayFormatter.format(new Date()));
```

Comment: I had been looking at that for hours yesterday. I just don't know how to use it. Looks like I'll have to learn it. Do you know any place that has a good tutorial?

Comment: Wow so this worked way easier when I went through the work to understand it. Thanks for you help. I still have much to do but I'm pushing along.

Comment: I do have one problem though. I have gotten the user imputed date but it will not refresh my button.  `startDate.setText(dayFormatter.format(cal.getTime()));`

Answer (score 1):

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/DayOfWeek.html suggests using Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK).

```
Calendar xmas = new GregorianCalendar(1998, Calendar.DECEMBER, 25);
int dayOfWeek = xmas.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);    // 6=Friday

Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2003, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);         // 4=Wednesday
```

Comment: This worked out super easy. I didn't know you could change the Calendar and then just call this.